# MySQL VARBINARY with maximum size

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I can't set varbinary with maximum size in MySql 8.0
Show this error message :
**Could not set value**

Please write correct syntax.
Thanks.

Comment: [create table test ( var varbinary(65535) NOT NULL)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdc8c998b0f9355b7911537bef278b5c) fails for me too. Be more explicit in your question about the syntax you tried and complete error message. Might be worthy of a bug report https://bugs.mysql.com/

Comment: by experimentation [VARBINARY(65533)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c8b2d3395c618cdbb98100da4b5b1ae) works. Alone. [Row size limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html) and [innodb row format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html) have effects and are worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, one can't use **'max'** as length like **SQL Server**. If you want a column with max size binary data, then `LONGBLOB` is a better option.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html

Answer (score 0):

setting `VARBINARY(65535)` will throw an error in mysql if you have other columns

> Query error:
> #1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

in my case setting it to `varbinary(65450)` was successful because I have 11 more columns to consider.